# how could i push view controller to navigation controller

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I want to go from my Login Page to the `MainMenuViewController` but the `MainMenuViewController` is a navigation Controller.

I searched for a while but it still doesn't work correctly. Could anyone tell me what's going on?

My code:

```
MainMenuViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"MainMenuViewController"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is the issue? This will present a view controller that you choose, if you want to get the navigation view to show up correctly you will want to transition not to the MainMenuViewController, but the root view controller for that.  When you look at the storyboard, you can see the navigation controller that segues to the MainMenuViewController, present that view controller instead of the MainMenuViewController.

Comment: it's worked!! My program conception isn't clear.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Set the storyboard ID for your navigation controller and write the below code in the function.

```
UINavigationController * navigationController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondNavigationController"];

[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope this helps. :)